# Annotation Attribute Overriding using @AliasFor

Tags: spring

I am Reading the docs for @AliasFor annotation in Spring, and one intresting thing is the ability to override annotation attribute, **Explicit Alias for Attribute in Meta-annotation**.

```
package com.mmeqbel.springcontainer;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.AliasFor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

public class SpringContainerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        System.out.println(applicationContext.getBeanDefinition("customWierdRepository"));
        System.out.println(applicationContext.getBeanDefinition("repo"));
    }

}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
class AppConfig { }

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
@interface CustomRepository {
    @AliasFor(annotation = Component.class, attribute = "value")
    String name() default "";
}

@CustomRepository(name = "repo")
class CustomWierdRepository {}
```

however i couldn't do it directly. by directly i mean declaring one attribute and make it an alias for the meta-annotation attribute

the result:

```
Generic bean: class [com.mmeqbel.springcontainer.CustomWierdRepository]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodNames=null; destroyMethodNames=null; defined in file [C:\Users\yahya\Documents\Learning\spring-container\target\classes\com\mmeqbel\springcontainer\CustomWierdRepository.class]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'repo' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893)
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.getBeanDefinition(GenericApplicationContext.java:360)
    at com.mmeqbel.springcontainer.SpringContainerApplication.main(SpringContainerApplication.java:16)
```